# Python. Tor-browser. VPN. Proxy

Tags: python, libraries, tor

I'm currently working on a project that anonymizes the user. Tell me please, whether it is possible to make with the help of Python the program which will redirect traffic through Tor, VPN, SSX in the necessary order. I started this program, then opened any browser and the traffic will pass as I described earlier. If possible, advise the modules and libraries that are on Python 3. Thank you very much!

Comment: Requests for suggested libraries are explicitly off-topic here. See #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Beyond that, "how do I build an application for purpose X?" is intrinsically overbroad -- designing any complete application has a wealth of individual decisions, and a question about how to build such a thing end-to-end has no complete and canonical answer.

Comment: See https://ipredator.se/netsplice